# Error with Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I am giving the codes of my JAVA files and hbm files along with the code I am using to fetch data.It is a many to many mapping. There is no annotations involved rather hbm file is used. Can anyone spot the mistake in the query I am making to fetch the data?

1. class SuggestValuesWrtProfiles:-This is a model class which is apart of the mapping.
2. ProfileField java class:This the other model class which is a part of the mapping.
3. SuggestValuesWrtProfiles hbm file:-the hibernate properties file used for mapping SuggestValuesWrtProfiles class.
4. ProfileField hbm file:-the hibernate properties file used for mapping ProfileField class.
5. my query to fetch a list of SuggestValuesWrtProfiles objects against a specific profile id.

I am unable to find the mistake. Can anyone please point it out?

1

```
import com.kivar.lumina.common.entity.Model;

public class SuggestValuesWrtProfiles extends Model {

    private Long suggest_values_id;

    private Integer domainRefKey;

    private String domainValue;

    private Set<ProfileField> profileId = new HashSet<ProfileField>();

    public SuggestValuesWrtProfiles() {

    }

    public SuggestValuesWrtProfiles( Integer domainRefKey, String domainValue ) {

        this.domainRefKey = domainRefKey;
        this.domainValue = domainValue;
    }

    public Long getSuggest_values_id() {
        return suggest_values_id;
    }

    public void setSuggest_values_id( Long suggest_values_id ) {
        this.suggest_values_id = suggest_values_id;
    }

    public Integer getDomainRefKey() {
        return domainRefKey;
    }

    public void setDomainRefKey( Integer domainRefKey ) {
        this.domainRefKey = domainRefKey;
    }

    public String getDomainValue() {
        return domainValue;
    }

    public void setDomainValue( String domainValue ) {
        this.domainValue = domainValue;
    }

    public Set<ProfileField> getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId( Set<ProfileField> profileId ) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

}
```

2

```
package com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.entities;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.kivar.lumina.server.application.SeedI18nHelper;
import com.kivar.lumina.server.hibernate.util.LuminaHibernateUtil;
import com.kivar.lumina.server.rule.entities.OperandConfiguration;

@Entity
public class ProfileField extends OperandConfiguration {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( ProfileField.class );

    private Integer internalId;

    private Integer version = 0;

    private String profileFieldTagId;

    private Boolean isTrended;

    private Integer profileFieldTypeDetailId;

    private Integer isComposite;

    private Integer profileFieldTypeId;

    private String visibility;

    private Long bunchingId;

    private Boolean isAdvancedTrendField;

    private String treePath;

    private Set<SuggestValuesWrtProfiles> suggestKey = new HashSet<SuggestValuesWrtProfiles>();

    public Integer getInternalId() {
        return internalId;
    }

    public void setInternalId( Integer internalId ) {
        this.internalId = internalId;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion( Integer version ) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString() {
        return SeedI18nHelper.getSeedProperty( "ProfileField.Name.", getName() );
    }

    public String getProfileFieldTagId() {
        return profileFieldTagId;
    }

    public void setProfileFieldTagId( String profileFieldTagId ) {
        this.profileFieldTagId = profileFieldTagId;
    }

    public Boolean getIsTrended() {
        return isTrended;
    }

    public void setIsTrended( Boolean trended ) {
        this.isTrended = trended;
    }

    public Integer getProfileFieldTypeDetailId() {
        return profileFieldTypeDetailId;
    }

    public void setProfileFieldTypeDetailId( Integer profileFieldTypeDetailId ) {
        this.profileFieldTypeDetailId = profileFieldTypeDetailId;
    }

    public Integer getIsComposite() {
        return isComposite;
    }

    public void setIsComposite( Integer isComposite ) {
        this.isComposite = isComposite;
    }

    public Integer getProfileFieldTypeId() {
        return profileFieldTypeId;
    }

    public void setProfileFieldTypeId( Integer profileFieldType ) {
        this.profileFieldTypeId = profileFieldType;
    }

    public String getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility( String visibility ) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public Long getBunchingId() {
        return bunchingId;
    }

    public void setBunchingId( Long bunchingId ) {
        this.bunchingId = bunchingId;
    }

    public Boolean getIsAdvancedTrendField() {
        return isAdvancedTrendField;
    }

    public void setIsAdvancedTrendField( Boolean isAdvancedTrendField ) {
        this.isAdvancedTrendField = isAdvancedTrendField;
    }

    public String getTreePath() {
        return treePath;
    }

    public void setTreePath( String treePath ) {
        this.treePath = treePath;
    }

    public Set<SuggestValuesWrtProfiles> getSuggestKey() {
        return suggestKey;
    }

    public void setSuggestKey( Set<SuggestValuesWrtProfiles> suggestKey ) {
        this.suggestKey = suggestKey;
    }

    public static ProfileField findProfileField( Long profile_id ) {
        Session session = LuminaHibernateUtil.getUtil().getNewSession();

        ProfileField pf = null;
        try {
            List<ProfileField> profile_fields = LuminaHibernateUtil.getUtil().getList( session.createQuery( " FROM com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.entities.ProfileField PF WHERE PF.id = " + profile_id ) );
            pf = profile_fields.get( 0 );
            if ( pf != null ) {
                logger.info( "Profile field is : " + pf.getName() + " id is : " + pf.getId() );
            }

        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return pf;
    }
}
```

3

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-mapping auto-import="false">
        <class name="com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.entities.SuggestValuesWrtProfiles"
        table="suggestvalues">
        <id column="suggest_values_id" name="suggest_values_id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="sequence-identity">
        <param name="sequence">suggestvalues_seq</param>
        </generator>
        </id>
        <!-- <many-to-one name="domainRefKey" class="com.pelatro.pfenum.hibernate.beans.ProfileField" column="domain_ref_key" fetch="select"></many-to-one> -->
        <property name="domainRefKey" column="domain_ref_key" /> 
        <property name="domainValue" column="domain_value"></property>

        <set name="profileId" table="profile_fields_suggestvalues"
        inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                    <key>
                        <column name="profile_fields_id" not-null="true" />
                    </key>
                    <many-to-many column="suggest_values_id" class="com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.entities.SuggestValuesWrtProfiles" />
                </set> 

        </class>
        </hibernate-mapping>
```

4

```
    <property name="name" column="name"></property>
    <property name="dataTypeId" column="data_type_id"></property>
    <property name="formatterTypeId" column="format_type"></property>
    <property name="internalId" column="internal_id"></property>
    <property name="profileFieldTagId" column="domain_tags"></property>
    <property name="profileFieldTypeDetailId" column="profile_field_type_detail_id"></property>
    <property name="isComposite" column="is_composite_type"></property>
    <property name="profileFieldTypeId" column="profile_field_type_id"></property>
    <property name="visibility" column="visibility"></property>
    <property name="treePath" column="tree_path"></property>

    <set name="suggestKey" table="profile_fields_suggestvalues"
    inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <key>
                    <column name="profile_fields_id" not-null="true" />
                </key>
                <many-to-many column="suggest_values_id" class="com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.entities.SuggestValuesWrtProfiles" />
            </set> 


    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

5

```
suggestedListValues = LuminaHibernateUtil.getUtil().getList( 
    session.createQuery( "select distinct SV FROM 
    com.kivar.lumina.server.segment.entities.SuggestValuesWrtProfiles SV 
    JOIN SV.profileId PFS where PFS.id=:id" ).setLong( "id", profile_id ) 
   );
```

Comment: What exception do you face can you post exception trace ?!

Comment: No I am unable to fetch values..getting an empty list....though if i do a eager loading I am fetching all the data